# Can I use asus charger for acer laptop?

Tags: windows-8

I forgot my charger at home and Im far at home. I am thinking if I could use my cousin's charger, but his laptop is asus brand x453m... and I am using acer laptop 4736Z?

Comment: 1. Check how many Amps does your laptop needs, usually Below the battery, or Google it. 2. Check how many Amps does the charger outputs. (Needs to Be equal to #1) 3. Check If the jack of the charger fits the laptop power socket

Comment: Charger output voltage should be within about 5%, output current should be equal or greater, The connector should match and have the same polarity.  Beyond that, certain manufacturers use techniques to check whether it's an OEM charger (I don't know if this applies to Asus or Acer).  If all of the other criteria are met and you try it and it works, you don't have to worry about this last item (no potential for damage to try it if it meets the other criteria).

Comment: @Alex Your statement is not true. The current does not need to be equal.

Comment: @David Schwartz agreed. But let's say we have a charger with 2.2 Amps output and the laptop works with only 1.75 Amps. If you try to power the laptop with this charger there are great chances to fry it.

Comment: @Alex No. That's not at all how it works. If you drink from a 10 liter bottle, does your stomache explode? Laptop power supplies are regulated, constant voltage supplies. Unless either the supply or the load is defective or the regulated output voltage is too low or too high, they cannot supply excessive current.

Answer (score 1):

According to [link1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004QGU56I) and also [link2](http://www.snapdeal.com/product/acer-laptop-adapter-original-genuine/64897637), your laptop charger probably has these specifications:

Output: DC19V 3.42A
Power: 65W Max

According to [this link](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/AC-Adapter-Charger-for-Asus-X453m-X453MA-F553M-X553MA-D553MA-15-6-Power-Supply-/281841010672) your cousin's laptop charger probably has these specifications:

Output: DC19V 1.75A-2.37A
Power:  45W

I'm not sure that cousin's charger's socket is compatible with your laptop so please push the socket slowly. if plug successfully, you can charge your laptop by this charger, however, your cousin's charger might be broken in long time use.

It's better that shutdown your laptop and then charge your laptop with your cousin's charger.

Comment: Just to add to Tom's answer, the supplied chargers typically have enough power to charge the battery while you use the laptop.  So your own charger likely can supply more power than required to do either task alone.  It may also be somewhat generic in that it is supplied for a range of laptop models (it can be cheaper for them to buy one powerful charger in great quantity than to buy a custom-tailored charger for each model).  Your cousin's charger has a lower capacity, so don't try to charge while using the laptop.  There's a good chance, though, that it will handle one task or the other.

Comment: (cont'd)  Check the label on your laptop to see if it shows a power requirement of 45W or less, in which case you should be able to do either task.  The laptop should be powered off when charging.  If the charger gets extremely hot when you try to use it, that's a sign that you're pulling more current than it's designed for, and you should stop to avoid possibly ruining the charger.